# jQuery show child elements if they have specific class

Tags: jquery, css, hide, show

I want to hide all the elements that don't have the .active class. The code I'm currently using doesn't seem to be working.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wv33Lu6e/)

HTML

```
<ul class="list">
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="active">Menu Item 2
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Menu Item 2.2
              </a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2.2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2.2.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Menu Item 2.2.3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
.list li { display: none; }
```

jQuery

```
$( document ).ready( function( ) {

    $(".menu > li").has(".active").show;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some typos:

1. Instead of using `.list` you've used `.menu`
2. Instead of using `.show()` you've used `.show`

Next to that I think you can make your jQuery a bit simpler:

```
$(function() {
  $(".list > li.active").show();
});
```

the `$(function() { ... })` does exactly the same as the `$(document).ready(function() { ... }`, and I've directly selected the `li` elements with class `.active` instead of first selecting the `li` elements and afterwards checking if they have the class `.active`.

If you want the entire menu structure to be shown (e.g. *Menu 2*, *Menu 2.2*, *Menu 2.2.3* you need to change `.list > li.active` into `.list li.active`. However this would also mean moving the `.active` class to the `li` instead of the `a` tags for the submenu's.

Another option altogether would be to use CSS instead of jQuery for this (although you might use jQuery for behaviour). Simply use `.list li.active { display: list-item; }` to show the *Menu 2*

```js
$(function() {
  $(".list > li.active").show();
});
```

```css
.list li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1.2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#" class="active">Menu Item 2
          </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2.1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Menu Item 2.2
              </a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2.2.1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2.2.2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="active">Menu Item 2.2.3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.show` is a function, it should be `.show()` and there is no element with class `.menu` in your markup, use `.list` instead(`.list > li`).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list > li").has(".active").show();
});
```

```css
.list li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1.2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#" class="active">Menu Item 2
       </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2.1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Menu Item 2.2
           </a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2.2.1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2.2.2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="active">Menu Item 2.2.3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler jQuery syntax (replaced .menu with .list, modified selector, modified the function syntax) :

```
$(function( ){
    $(".list li.active").show();
});
```

This one will only target first level li's by the way :

```
$(function( ){
    $(".list > li.active").show();
});
```